# Unable to get dynamic PHP's Object value using PHP variable

Tags: php, object, dynamic

PHP is unable to get the value for dynamic object prepared as:

```
$abc->{$dynamic_object_pattern}
```

Where the value of the variable **$dynamic_object_pattern** is, **json->{'data_1'}->{'value'}**

For me, PHP 7.1 is understanding the statically defined pattern like below, and fetching the value as it should:

```
$abc->json->{'data_1'}->{'value'}
```

But not when I put the whole portion into a variable and then try to get its value. I Tried,

**$abc->{$dynamic_object_pattern}** and **$abc->$dynamic_object_pattern**

both ways, but no solution yet.
The error comes is ****Notice**: Undefined property: stdClass::$json->{'data_1'}->{'value'}**

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($abc);` to see what is actually in the object first?

Comment: Yes, already saw that. It has the value with the same indexes

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting an answer without seeing your JSON data

Here you say :

> But not when I put the whole portion into a variable and then try to
>   get its value

From that line alone it sounds like you are trying to get value from a string rather than array. If you put the whole portion into a variable, PHP will interpret it as string. Make sure you add `array()` before newly created variable.

Natural array :

```
$array = array();
```

Now a string

```
$variable = $array;
```

Convert string to array

```
$new_array = array($variable);
```

Also, have you tried decoding?

```
// decode
$response = json_decode($new_array, true);

//print out
var_export(array_unique(array($response)));
```